# Multifractal Model, Generating Sample Paths with Correlations between Assets

Tags: time-series, correlation, returns, fractals

I have studied option pricing using Geometric Brownian Motion to generate sample paths. Because of the normal distribution, it is easy to create a covariance matrix and get correlated asset returns.

I am interested in learning more about Mandelbrot's Multi Fractal model of asset returns and it's applications. From what I can find, there exist much work about forecasting volatility using the multi fractal model.

For my purposes, I am more interested in being able to generate sample paths, i.e. produce time series data. Further I would be interested in somehow modeling correlation between assets.

Does there exist papers dealing with these problems from the viewpoint of the multi fractal model of asset returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper ["A Multifractal Model of Asset Returns"](http://wstein.org/home/wstein/www/home/simuw/simuw08/refs/fractal/mandelbrot-a_multifractal_model_of_asset_returns.pdf) by B. Mandelbrot, A. Fisher and L. Calvet (1997) discusses the creation of multifractal processes in Section 3.4.

Comment: Thanks. That's great. I also found this page that I didn't find the first time for some reason: http://users.math.yale.edu/mandelbrot/webbooks/wb_fin.html

Answer (score 4):

Not acutally a paper, but there is even a book on Multifractal Models. It is, to my knowledge, the standard reference on this topic by Calvet and Fisher:

[Multifractal Volatility: Theory, Forecasting, and Pricing (Academic Press Advanced Finance)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121500136)